# Rails Ajax Error: "Turbolinks is not defined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I'm using Rails 4.2 and I want to send an ajax request to my server. But the request always fails with the error `Turbolinks is not defined`. My rails console returns a 200 ok response.
I am using the ['jquery-turbolinks'](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem.

Thanks in advance!

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: "http://localhost:3000",
  data: xx,
  success: function(data){
     alert("success");
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert("some error");
  }
});
```

Controller

```
  def upvote
     # code here
     @vote.save
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to :back }
       format.json { head :ok }
       format.js { head :ok }
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In application.js, are you requiring jquery.turbolinks between jquery and turbolinks like below?

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

If your turbolinks version is 5, jquery-turbolinks gem doesn't support turbolinks 5. 
So, at the moment, you have to add JS for compatibility reffering [this issue](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/61) (see Lowryderch's comment).
Put the turbolinks-compatibility.coffee under app/assets/javascripts/ folder.

Comment: I believe he is

Comment: Have you installed `masonry-rails` gem and required `masonry/jquery.masonry` in application.js? ( I updated my answer)

Comment: I have installed masonry-rails

Comment: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require social-share-button
//= require_tree .
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

Comment: I guess you're using turbolinks 5, and jquery-turbolinks doesn't support that yet. I had same problem and my JS didn't work, but I solved with my updated answer.

Comment: Just updated it, but it still breaks the jquery masonry.

Comment: Adding turbolinks-compatibility.coffee doesn't worked?

Comment: I added the new coffee script, but it still breaks.